# How to show contribution items in CiviReports for Contribution Reports

Tags: contributions, line-items

I have contribution items in a single contribution report and need to show a quantity of an item purchased in a month.

What is the ideal way to get quantity used for a month in multiple contributions.

I dont see the option for the same.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are referring to are line items - if the contributions in question are event contributions, then you can use [**Extended Report**](https://civicrm.org/extensions/extended-reports) - "Participant Line Items" that will allow you to filter by event, otherwise, [**Extended Report**](https://civicrm.org/extensions/extended-reports) - "Contributions with Price Set Data" should also show you what you need- but it may take a bit of trial and error, i.e. the report offers several grouping options for line items:

- Price Field Label
- Price Field Value Label
- Line Item Financial Type
- Price Field (line item)
- Price Field Option (line item)

You'll want to select whatever option(s) you are grouping by as display columns as well as the following columns:

- Quantity
- Line Total
- Unit Price (if interesting)

E.g. Grouping by Price Field Option (line item) will yield the following:

[image]

Hope this helps!
Tamar